# Local Key/Value Store vs native dictionary/hashmap object

Tags: database, performance

Any good reason to use something like Redis instead of a native dictionary collection, if you don't need persistence?

Let's assume you have millions of entries, but they all fit comfortably in memory and you don't need durability.

Am I right in thinking that gets/puts in the native object will almost always be faster than a key/value store?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

The only reasons I can think of to use a key-value store of you don't actually need persistence would be if it gave you some efficient search interface (like Tokyo Cabinet's table database) or if it handled massively concurrent updates better.